# HTTParty gives me 'Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 8881' in >= Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

This is a weird error. I'm in the process of upgrading a Rails 3.2.21 app to Ruby 2.  Everything works fine, but when I want to make any HTTP requests using HTTParty within Rails, I get the following error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 8881
    from /Users/stuart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
    from /Users/stuart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
    from /Users/stuart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
    from /Users/stuart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
    from /Users/stuart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
    from /Users/stuart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from /Users/stuart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from /Users/stuart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1369:in `request'
    from /Users/stuart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httparty-0.13.5/lib/httparty/request.rb:101:in `perform'
    from /Users/stuart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httparty-0.13.5/lib/httparty.rb:522:in `perform_request'
    from /Users/stuart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httparty-0.13.5/lib/httparty.rb:460:in `get'
    from /Users/stuart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httparty-0.13.5/lib/httparty.rb:560:in `get'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/stuart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/stuart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/stuart/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

If I try and connect to the same URL using any other method (web browser, cURL, Net::HTTP), I can get the URL fine. Even if I run `irb` and require HTTParty and make the same request, it works.

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.21'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# gem "mongoid", "~> 3.0.0"
# gem 'bson_ext'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'haml', '>= 3.1.3'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'less-rails'
  gem 'less-rails-bootstrap', '~> 2.3.3'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails-confirm'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :test do
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'coveralls'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'mocha', require: false
  gem 'test-unit'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'csvlint', github: 'theodi/csvlint.rb'
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'shoulda-context'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :development do
  gem 'guard', '~> 1.8.3'
  gem 'guard-test'
  # gem 'spring', github: 'jonleighton/spring'
  gem 'terminal-notifier-guard'
  gem 'ruby-prof'
  gem 'rails-footnotes', '>= 3.7.9'
  gem 'rubyXL'
end

group :production do
  gem 'foreman'
  gem 'mysql2'
  gem 'airbrake'
  gem 'delayed-plugins-airbrake'
  gem 'logstash-event'
  gem 'lograge'
end

group :surveyor do
  gem 'fastercsv', '~> 1.5.4'
  gem 'formtastic', '~> 2.1.0'
  gem 'uuidtools', '~> 2.1'
  gem 'mustache', '0.99.4'
  gem 'rabl', '~>0.6.13'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

#To serve static content / styleguide
gem 'high_voltage'

# states of the questionnaires
gem 'aasm'

# authorization
gem 'cancan'

# pagination
gem 'kaminari'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'
gem 'thin'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

gem "ransack"
gem 'surveyor', path: 'vendor/gems/surveyor-1.4.0'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem "devise", "3.0.3"
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'data_kitten', github: 'theodi/data_kitten'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'linkeddata'
gem 'rack-linkeddata'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'rack-cors', require: 'rack/cors'
gem 'alternate_rails', :github => 'theodi/alternate-rails'
gem 'fog'
gem 'juvia_rails', github: 'theodi/juvia_rails'
gem 'domainatrix'
# newrelic appears to be adding significant performance problems
#gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'google_drive'
gem 'pry-remote'
gem 'memoist'
gem 'validate_url'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra', :require => nil
```

And my Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/theodi/alternate-rails.git
  revision: 188889d66c5df1d7d13f7c6e53e8088e3503dea1
  specs:
    alternate_rails (0.0.1)
      rails (~> 3.2.13)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/theodi/csvlint.rb.git
  revision: 3dc689f4625c8edd4f7b725d1d420fdd67a67df9
  specs:
    csvlint (0.0.1)
      activesupport
      addressable
      colorize
      mime-types
      open_uri_redirections

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/theodi/data_kitten.git
  revision: ddcbb677d7d993091a8f2ca44e537aa5cfd63bb8
  specs:
    data_kitten (1.2.0)
      curb
      datapackage
      git
      json
      linkeddata
      nokogiri
      rake
      rest-client

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/theodi/juvia_rails.git
  revision: 94f982aa8188a18bc0f37c16218c85e890d25294
  specs:
    juvia_rails (0.0.1)
      rails (~> 3.2.1)

PATH
  remote: vendor/gems/surveyor-1.4.0
  specs:
    surveyor (1.4.0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    aasm (3.1.1)
    actionmailer (3.2.21)
      actionpack (= 3.2.21)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (3.2.21)
      activemodel (= 3.2.21)
      activesupport (= 3.2.21)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.21)
      activesupport (= 3.2.21)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.21)
      activemodel (= 3.2.21)
      activesupport (= 3.2.21)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.21)
      activemodel (= 3.2.21)
      activesupport (= 3.2.21)
    activesupport (3.2.21)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.3.5)
    airbrake (4.1.0)
      builder
      multi_json
    arel (3.0.3)
    bcrypt (3.1.7)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
      bcrypt (>= 3.1.3)
    builder (3.0.4)
    cancan (1.6.10)
    capybara (2.4.1)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    celluloid (0.16.0)
      timers (~> 4.0.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
    colorize (0.7.3)
    commonjs (0.2.7)
    connection_pool (2.1.0)
    coveralls (0.7.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      rest-client
      simplecov (>= 0.7)
      term-ansicolor
      thor
    crack (0.4.2)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0.0)
    cucumber (1.3.16)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
      gherkin (~> 2.12)
      multi_json (>= 1.7.5, < 2.0)
      multi_test (>= 0.1.1)
    cucumber-rails (1.4.1)
      capybara (>= 1.1.2, < 3)
      cucumber (>= 1.3.8, < 2)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rails (>= 3, < 5)
    curb (0.8.8)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    database_cleaner (1.3.0)
    datapackage (0.0.4)
      colorize
      json
      json-schema
      rest-client
    delayed-plugins-airbrake (1.1.0)
      airbrake
      delayed_job
    delayed_job (4.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
    delayed_job_active_record (4.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
      delayed_job (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
    devise (3.0.3)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    docile (1.1.3)
    domainatrix (0.0.11)
      addressable
    dotenv (0.10.0)
    dotenv-rails (0.10.0)
      dotenv (= 0.10.0)
    ebnf (0.3.6)
      haml (~> 4.0)
      rdf (~> 1.1)
      sxp (~> 0.1, >= 0.1.3)
    equivalent-xml (0.5.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.3)
    excon (0.31.0)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    factory_girl (4.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.4.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.4.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faraday (0.9.0)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    fastercsv (1.5.5)
    ffi (1.9.3)
    fog (1.20.0)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.31.0)
      formatador (~> 0.2.0)
      mime-types
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      net-scp (~> 1.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.1.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.11)
    foreman (0.63.0)
      dotenv (>= 0.7)
      thor (>= 0.13.6)
    formatador (0.2.4)
    formtastic (2.1.1)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
    gherkin (2.12.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
    git (1.2.9.1)
    google_drive (0.3.9)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4, != 1.5.2, != 1.5.1)
      oauth (>= 0.3.6)
      oauth2 (>= 0.5.0)
    guard (1.8.3)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (~> 1.3)
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.2)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
      thor (>= 0.14.6)
    guard-test (1.0.0)
      guard (>= 1.8)
      test-unit (~> 2.2)
    haml (4.0.5)
      tilt
    high_voltage (2.1.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    hitimes (1.2.2)
    htmlentities (4.3.2)
    httparty (0.13.5)
      json (~> 1.8)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (0.6.11)
    jbuilder (2.0.4)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2.0)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (3.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    json-ld (1.1.6)
      rdf (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.4)
    json-schema (2.5.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    jwt (0.1.13)
      multi_json (>= 1.5)
    kaminari (0.15.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    less (2.3.3)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.6)
    less-rails (2.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      less (~> 2.3.1)
    less-rails-bootstrap (2.3.3)
      less-rails (~> 2.3.1)
    libv8 (3.16.14.7)
    linkeddata (1.1.1)
      equivalent-xml (>= 0.4.0)
      json-ld (>= 1.1.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6.1)
      rdf (>= 1.1.1)
      rdf-aggregate-repo (>= 1.1.0)
      rdf-isomorphic (>= 1.1.0)
      rdf-json (>= 1.1.0)
      rdf-microdata (>= 1.1.1)
      rdf-n3 (>= 1.1.0)
      rdf-rdfa (>= 1.1.1)
      rdf-rdfxml (>= 1.1.0)
      rdf-trig (>= 1.1.2)
      rdf-trix (>= 1.1.0)
      rdf-turtle (>= 1.1.2)
      sparql (>= 1.1.2)
      sparql-client (>= 1.1.1)
    listen (1.3.1)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
      rb-kqueue (>= 0.2)
    lograge (0.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 3)
      activesupport (>= 3)
      railties (>= 3)
    logstash-event (1.2.02)
    lumberjack (1.0.4)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    memoist (0.9.3)
    metaclass (0.0.4)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.0)
    mocha (1.1.0)
      metaclass (~> 0.0.1)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    multi_test (0.1.1)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    mustache (0.99.4)
    mysql2 (0.3.15)
    net-http-persistent (1.9)
    net-scp (1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.8.0)
    netrc (0.7.7)
    nokogiri (1.6.3.1)
      mini_portile (= 0.6.0)
    oauth (0.4.7)
    oauth2 (0.9.3)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      jwt (~> 0.1.8)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    open_uri_redirections (0.1.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    polyamorous (0.6.4)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    pry (0.9.12.6)
      coderay (~> 1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry-remote (0.1.8)
      pry (~> 0.9)
      slop (~> 3.0)
    rabl (0.6.14)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.14)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-cors (0.4.0)
    rack-linkeddata (1.1.0)
      linkeddata (>= 1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.4)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-ssl (1.3.4)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.21)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.21)
      actionpack (= 3.2.21)
      activerecord (= 3.2.21)
      activeresource (= 3.2.21)
      activesupport (= 3.2.21)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.21)
    rails-footnotes (3.7.9)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
    railties (3.2.21)
      actionpack (= 3.2.21)
      activesupport (= 3.2.21)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.0)
    ransack (1.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
      polyamorous (~> 0.6.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
    rb-inotify (0.9.3)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rb-kqueue (0.2.2)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdf (1.1.6)
    rdf-aggregate-repo (1.1.0)
      rdf (>= 1.1)
    rdf-isomorphic (1.1.0)
      rdf (>= 1.1)
    rdf-json (1.1.0)
      rdf (>= 1.1.0)
    rdf-microdata (1.1.2)
      htmlentities (~> 4.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rdf (~> 1.1)
      rdf-xsd (~> 1.1)
    rdf-n3 (1.1.2)
      rdf (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.5)
    rdf-rdfa (1.1.4)
      haml (~> 4.0)
      htmlentities (~> 4.3)
      rdf (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.6)
      rdf-xsd (~> 1.1)
    rdf-rdfxml (1.1.1)
      rdf (~> 1.1)
      rdf-rdfa (~> 1.1)
      rdf-xsd (~> 1.1)
    rdf-trig (1.1.3.1)
      ebnf (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.5)
      rdf (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.2.1)
      rdf-turtle (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.3)
    rdf-trix (1.1.0)
      rdf (>= 1.1)
    rdf-turtle (1.1.4)
      ebnf (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.6)
      rdf (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.4)
    rdf-xsd (1.1.1)
      rdf (~> 1.1)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redcarpet (3.1.1)
    redis (3.2.1)
    redis-namespace (1.5.2)
      redis (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.4)
    ref (1.0.5)
    rest-client (1.7.2)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0)
      netrc (~> 0.7)
    ruby-prof (0.14.2)
    rubyXL (3.3.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      rubyzip (>= 1.1.6)
    rubyzip (1.1.6)
    safe_yaml (1.0.3)
    sass (3.2.14)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    shoulda (3.5.0)
      shoulda-context (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
      shoulda-matchers (>= 1.4.1, < 3.0)
    shoulda-context (1.1.6)
    shoulda-matchers (2.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    sidekiq (2.17.2)
      celluloid (>= 0.15.2)
      connection_pool (>= 1.0.0)
      json
      redis (>= 3.0.6)
      redis-namespace (>= 1.3.1)
    simplecov (0.8.2)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      multi_json
      simplecov-html (~> 0.8.0)
    simplecov-html (0.8.0)
    sinatra (1.4.6)
      rack (~> 1.4)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    slop (3.4.7)
    sparql (1.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.0)
      ebnf (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.5)
      rdf (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.4)
      rdf-aggregate-repo (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.0)
      rdf-xsd (~> 1.1)
      sparql-client (~> 1.1)
      sxp (~> 0.1)
    sparql-client (1.1.3)
      net-http-persistent (~> 1.4)
      rdf (~> 1.1)
    sprockets (2.2.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.9)
    sxp (0.1.5)
    term-ansicolor (1.3.0)
      tins (~> 1.0)
    terminal-notifier-guard (1.5.3)
    test-unit (2.5.5)
    therubyracer (0.12.1)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
      ref
    thin (1.6.2)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 1.0.0)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timecop (0.7.1)
    timers (4.0.1)
      hitimes
    tins (1.1.0)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    twitter-bootstrap-rails-confirm (1.0.2)
    tzinfo (0.3.42)
    uglifier (2.4.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    uuidtools (2.1.4)
    validate_url (0.2.2)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      addressable
    vcr (2.9.0)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    webmock (1.17.4)
      addressable (>= 2.2.7)
      crack (>= 0.3.2)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  aasm
  airbrake
  alternate_rails!
  cancan
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  coveralls
  csvlint!
  cucumber-rails
  data_kitten!
  database_cleaner
  delayed-plugins-airbrake
  delayed_job_active_record
  devise (= 3.0.3)
  domainatrix
  dotenv-rails
  factory_girl_rails (~> 4.0)
  fastercsv (~> 1.5.4)
  fog
  foreman
  formtastic (~> 2.1.0)
  google_drive
  guard (~> 1.8.3)
  guard-test
  haml (>= 3.1.3)
  high_voltage
  httparty
  jbuilder
  jquery-rails
  juvia_rails!
  kaminari
  less-rails
  less-rails-bootstrap (~> 2.3.3)
  linkeddata
  lograge
  logstash-event
  memoist
  mocha
  mustache (= 0.99.4)
  mysql2
  pry
  pry-remote
  rabl (~> 0.6.13)
  rack-cors
  rack-linkeddata
  rails (~> 3.2.21)
  rails-footnotes (>= 3.7.9)
  ransack
  redcarpet
  ruby-prof
  rubyXL
  sass
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  shoulda
  shoulda-context
  sidekiq
  sinatra
  sqlite3
  surveyor!
  terminal-notifier-guard
  test-unit
  therubyracer
  thin
  timecop
  twitter-bootstrap-rails-confirm
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  uuidtools (~> 2.1)
  validate_url
  vcr
  webmock
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show the irb session that you used?

Comment: $ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'httparty'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> response = HTTParty.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow')
=> #<HTTParty::Response:0x7fde7253f6d0 ... snip

Comment: Looks like it's related to some dependency - if I do `Bundler.require` in the irb session, I get the same issue. Just a case of what dependency

Comment: Is your server on port 8881? Do you receive that error when you make the request with HTTParty, or right after you do `Bundler.require`?

Comment: The error happens when I make the HTTParty request. I don't have anything running on port 8881 AFAIK.